# vba excel to powerpoint ppPasteHTML not working

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am trying to copy excel range to powerpoint (2007) using VBA. The code works fine to copy as image, however I need to copy as HTML table to allow editing. OLE objeect format works as well but that makes the powerpoint too bulky. Not sure why HTML format give the below error

"Run-time error -2147188160

Shapes (unknown member) : Invalid request. Clipboard is empty or contains data which may not be pasted here"

```
    Sub CopyFullCutToPresentation()
    'Step 1: Declare variables
      Dim PP As PowerPoint.Application
      Dim PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
      Dim PPSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
      Dim SlideTitle As String
      Dim h As Integer, k As Integer

      file = "F:\SIP\xlsm\sample.pptx"
    'Step 2: Create PowerPoint presentation
      Set PP = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
      PP.Visible = True
      Set PPPres = PP.Presentations.Open(file)


      h = 1
      k = 1
    'Step 3: Add slides
      Do While h < 450
        Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides.Add(k, ppLayoutTitleOnly)
        PPSlide.Select
    'Step 4: Copy the range as a picture
        Sheets("Full Cut Report").Select
        'Sheets("Full Cut Report").Range(Cells(h, 1), Cells(h + 5, 13)).CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
        Sheets("Full Cut Report").Range(Cells(h, 1), Cells(h + 5, 13)).Copy
    'Step 5: Paste the picture and adjust its position
        PPSlide.Select
        'PPSlide.Shapes.Paste.Select
        PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteHTML ' ppPasteEnhancedMetafile ' '(ERROR) here
        'PP.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True
        'PP.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignMiddles, True
        PP.Activate

        k = k + 1
        h = h + 6
    Loop
    'Step 6: Memory Cleanup
      Set PPSlide = Nothing
      Set PPPres = Nothing
      Set PP = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Comment: In your code snipplet you don't show us how you access excel. "Sheets" are obviously an excel part. Did you tried to import it in e.g. word?

Comment: The macro is running out of the source excel workbook. i.e. the data is in the excel workbook on the "Full Cut Report" tab. i am able to copy data without any issues in picture format. only when i try to use HTML it doesn't work.

Comment: The question is what exactly doesn't work. Can you copy the content in the clipboard or is the problem to paste it. So you can create a html doc in word, copy it and try to paste, copy from excel and paste to word. What works what not. Are there any error messages?